# Invalid Qualifier VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, offset, qualifiers

I want to set a variable to a cell and be able to reference that cell later on.

So I set cell D2 as a string whose value is the word "medium". I am currently doing this and it works:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Round(Application.Max(Range([D2].Offset(1, 0), [D2].Offset(2, 0))) / 1000, 2)
```

but instead of using [D2], since I want to run a `For` loop to do this multiple times in my code I want to say:

```
LoadCase = [D2]
LoadCaseNeg = [D2].offset(8,0)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Round(Application.Max(Range(LoadCase.Offset(1, 0), LoadCaseNeg.Offset(1, 0))) / 1000, 2)
```

however this doesn't work and gives me an *invalid qualifier* error,
I'm new to VBA so is there any better way to do this?

Comment: it would be `range("a1:a100").offset`  what is LoadCaseNeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Range` variable:

```
Dim LoadCase As Range
Set LoadCase = Range("D2")
```

You would similarly need to use `Set` for `LoadCaseNeg` (which should also be declared to be a range variable):

```
Set LoadCaseNeg = LoadCase.offset(8,0)
```

`[D2]` is a way to refer to the *value* which is contained in the cell, not the cell itself. You can also refer to that value as `Range("D2").Value` or `LoadCase.Value` (once you set the variable). The square bracket notation isn't used all that often in VBA code since it isn't very flexible.

Any basic book/tutorial on Excel VBA should explain how to work with range variables. They are the work-horse of Excel VBA programming.

Comment: Actually `[D2]` is referring to the *value* only through an implicit *default member* access; had OP prepended `Set` to the assignment, `[D2]` would have referred to the `Range` object. Square brackets are really nothing more than (questionable) syntax sugar for `Application.Evaluate`. You can verify this in the immediate pane: `?TypeName([D2])` prints `Range` ;-)